# What's wrong with my kivy configuration and how do I fix it in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, kivy, kivy-language, python-3.12

I am using kivy for an application in python and I think I configured the installation of kivy incorrectly. I'm trying to use a KV file and reference a root class. Since the Builder loads the file, there is no class for the KV file to reference and I get a "'FloatLayout' has no attribute 'test'" error. But if I create a class in the KV file, and then return the reference class, it will not display the button. If I try and reference the method placed in Tracker(app) class, that does nothing. What do I need to change with either my configuration or my code to fix my issue?

This problem persists in the app I'm working on and also this test-code below.

IDE is Visual Studios if that matters

```
(.py file)
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


class One(FloatLayout):
    
    def test(self):
        print("Clicked")
        

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        print("Running")
        #return One()
        return Builder.load_file("one.kv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()

(KV file)
#<One>:
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        text: "Enter"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100, 50
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_press: root.test()
```

I want to be able to click the button and "Clicked" be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `FloatLayout` in your `kv` file to `One`:

```
One:
    Button:
        text: "Enter"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100, 50
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_press: root.test()
```